# How do I indicate that fields are mandatory in Windows Desktop UI?

Tags: forms, windows-os, winforms

I need a method of indicating that certain fields are required within my forms on a Windows Desktop UI.

I have read and searched the Windows Design Guidelines, but can not find a standard that Windows suggests to use. Is there a standard method in Windows of indicating this?

**Windows Design Guidelines:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn688964.aspx

I know that a common method is to use an asterix beside required fields, is this the standard on Windows too?

N.b. I am not referring to validation messages or feedback after a user has interacted with a form, I am referring to the display of the form on initial load.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft does actually provide [some guidance for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742499.aspx#Required_input) in the context of dialog boxes. They suggest a few different approaches which are similar to those found on the web, and to some extent in Mac OS.

> To indicate that users must provide information in a control, consider
>   the following options:
>
> - **Don't indicate anything but handle missing required input with error messages.** This approach reduces clutter and works well if most
>     input is optional or users aren't likely to skip controls, thus
>     keeping the number of error messages low.
> - **Indicate required input using an asterisk at the beginning of the label.** Explain the asterisk using either:
>
>   - A footnote at the bottom of the content area that says * Required input.
>   - A tooltip on the asterisk that says Required input.
>
> This approach works well if there aren't many required controls, but
>   poorly if most controls are required. **If all controls require input,
>   state "All input required" at an appropriate place at the top of the
>   content area.** This approach reduces clutter for this specific case.

Comment: Why did they put that section under 'Dialog Boxes'... thanks for providing that link, exactly what I was after

Comment: @Matt_Obee That's the best example I've ever seen of how a UX.SE answer should be written.